# Testing Websockets in Springboot without STOMP and SockJs

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, websocket, spring-websocket

I'm working on writing unit test cases for WebSocket implementation in Springboot without STOMP and SockJs. The basic functionality is working properly when I'm testing it manually.

But the following unit test case failed when I tried.

```
@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    ResultActions resultActions = mvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.request(HttpMethod.GET,
            new URI("ws://localhost:8080" + WEBSOCKET_ENDPOINT))
            .header("Connection", "Upgrade")
            .header("Upgrade", "websocket")
            .header("Sec-WebSocket-Version", "13")
            .header("Sec-WebSocket-Key", "some_key"));
    resultActions.andExpect(status().isOk());
}
```

I'm getting following error on running this test case.

> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.socket.server.HandshakeFailureException:
>
> Uncaught failure for request ws://localhost/websockets;
>
> nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No 'javax.websocket.server.ServerContainer' ServletContext attribute. Are you running in a Servlet container that supports JSR-356?

Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: Did you have any luck testing your websocket without STOMP and SockJs. I'd be curious to see as I'm starting to do this too.

Comment: I couldn't write the test cases, but the desired functionality is implemented without STOMP.

Comment: That's a shame that you weren't able to get the test cases written - but understandable. Did you end up implementing your own message router then too?